# NullPointerException even after inflating the fragment

Tags: android, fragment

MainFragment Class: (gridview is null even after inflating)

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), thumbnails)); //gridview is null!!!

        getActivity().setTitle(title);
        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_main.xml layout

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
```

you have to use view not `getActivity()` to call `findViewById`

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
```

since your `GridView` belongs to the `Layout` you are inflating